# Can't get Avrcp focus in Service to proper Media Key event receive

Tags: android, service, android-mediasession

I have Service which starts with QuickSettigs Tile. This service should receive MEDIA_BUTTON event from bluetooth headset. It's working until I start any media player application Activity (not service!).

How to represent problem:

1. Start MyService - CLICK BT MEDIA_BUTTON - event catched by MyService
2. Stop MyService - CLICK BT MEDIA_BUTTON - media player application starts
3. CLICK BT MEDIA_BUTTON - media player catch stop event
4. Start MyService - CLICK BT MEDIA_BUTTON - event catched by MyService
5. Open media player application Activity
6. Press home button to minimize media player application Activity
7. Start MyService - CLICK BT MEDIA_BUTTON - **media player catch event** (wait why?! MyService MediaSession is active!)
8. Stop MyService
9. Start MyService - CLICK BT MEDIA_BUTTON - **media player catch event**
10. Stop MyService
11. Start MyApplication Activity
12. Press home button to minimize MyApplication Activity
13. Start MyService - CLICK BT MEDIA_BUTTON - **event catched by MyService** GOTO:1

I tried:

- Get AudioFocus with AudioManager - focus gains
- Play sound with MediaPlayer - nothing changes

But nothing solves problem.

After first Media player Activity start Avrcp focus locked: when I start MyService, in logcat Avrcp service says that its focus gained by media player application (e.g DDB2 or Phonograph) and I can't get it (Avrcp focus, not AudioFocus) back.

```
V Avrcp   : Active sessions changed, 1 sessions
V Avrcp   : Updating media controller to android.media.session.MediaController@5658a74
V Avrcp   : Metadata updated but no change!
V Avrcp   : updatePlayPauseState, state: null device: null
V Avrcp   : Device: no name: 
I Avrcp   : updatePlayStatusForDevice: device: null
V Avrcp   : Focus gained for player: com.kabouzeid.gramophone
D Avrcp   : Exit updateCurrentMediaController()
D Avrcp   : Exit onActiveSessionsChanged()
V Avrcp   : Active sessions changed, 1 sessions
V Avrcp   : Updating media controller to android.media.session.MediaController@6237b9d
V Avrcp   : Metadata updated but no change!
V Avrcp   : updatePlayPauseState, state: null device: null
V Avrcp   : Device: no name: 
I Avrcp   : updatePlayStatusForDevice: device: null
V Avrcp   : Focus gained for player: com.kabouzeid.gramophone
D Avrcp   : Exit updateCurrentMediaController()
D Avrcp   : Exit onActiveSessionsChanged()
V Avrcp   : MSG_UPDATE_RCC_CHANGE
V Avrcp   : processRCCStateChange: com.kabouzeid.gramophone
V Avrcp   : MSG_UPDATE_RCC_CHANGE
V Avrcp   : processRCCStateChange: com.kabouzeid.gramophone
V Avrcp   : updateAddressedMediaPlayer
V Avrcp   : current Player: 0
V Avrcp   : Requested Player: 0
V Avrcp   : updateAddressedMediaPlayer
V Avrcp   : current Player: 0
V Avrcp   : Requested Player: 0
```

I can't understand how MediaService really works in Android. How to debug this?

Comment: Maybe this would help “MediaBrowserServiceCompat and the modern media playback app” @ianhlake https://medium.com/google-developers/mediabrowserservicecompat-and-the-modern-media-playback-app-7959a5196d90